# Angular JS don't load value in the scope from function javascript

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularjs-scope

I'm trying getting data from firebase and apply in my scope.timeline.
I have a function timelineDB to access firebase and return values.

Debugging my code, I receive values in some points.

```
$scope.timeline = timelineDB(); 
console.log($scope.timeline); //Here I have value
```

But this value don't reflect in scope.timeline when I call in index.html, your value is null.

```
{{timeline}}
[]
```

Version:

```
/**
 * @license AngularJS v1.6.6
 * (c) 2010-2017 Google, Inc. http://angularjs.org
 * License: MIT
 */
```

File javascript:

```
    function timelineDB(){    
    const db = firebase.database();
        const ref = db.ref('timeline/-L-g_Ea4colCKXtMstqE');
        ref.orderByChild('data').on('value', showData, showError);
        var itens = [];
        function showData(item){
            item.forEach(function(child){
            console.log(child.val());
            itens.push({data: child.val().data});
            })
        }

        function showError(err){
            console.log(err);
        } 
        console.log(itens);
        return itens;
    };
```

File index.html

```
angular.module("horizontalTimeline", []);
        angular.module("horizontalTimeline").controller("horizontalTimelineCtrl", function($scope){ //, $http           
            $scope.timeline = [];                   
            $scope.timeline = timelineDB(); 
            console.log($scope.timeline); //Here I have value
            $scope.$apply(); //Don't works
});
{{timeline}} //NULL
```

Comment: Hey, it looks like you spelled items wrong when you first initialize it in your function and when you return it! Just update the spelling and that may fix your issue.

Comment: It seems right.

    var itens = [];
    itens.push({data: child.val().data});
    return itens;
```

Comment: Alright, I see that now.  What  error are you getting? And what data are you getting back from your db? More information on this issue would be really helpful.